# TS-Why the key is underline then I defined the type?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

we can see it on the screen capture, in ficheUserData , newFiche is a string. But in VSCode newFiche is underline with this information : "Property 'newFiche' does not exist on Type etc

I don't understand why it made this ?

screen 1
[image]

screen 2
[image]

Comment: `ficheUserData` is an *array*. You can access elements with an index. `ficheUserData[0].newFiche`

Comment: thank you, it works I would never have thought of that because the application works correctly before the switch to typescript

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)